# Spark job fails due to stackoverflow error

Tags: apache-spark

My spark job is using Mllib to train a LogisticRegression on a data but it fails due to the Stackoverflow error, here is the error message shown in the spark-shell

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion.apply(GenericCompanion.scala:48)
...
```

when I check the Spark UI, there is no failed stage or job! This is how I run my spark-shell

```
spark-shell --num-executors 100 --driver-memory 20g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=5g --executor-memory 8g --executor-cores 3
```

I even tried to increase the size of the stack by adding the following line when running the spark-shell, but it didn't help

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-XX:ThreadStackSize=81920'"
```

What the issue is?

Comment: Can you add your code snippet? I think this issue in this stack show Scala Collection Error. The stack didn't reach Spark classes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get your point, could you elaborate more?Actually my code is part of a bigger application. The code works fine on some data sets (smaller data sets or the same data set with fewer columns). It throws this stackoverflow when the number of columns grows

Comment: is it when there are more than 22 columns?
http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7910

Comment: No, I'm reading a Hive table and it has 2.2K columns. when I use 1500 column it works fine but if I use all the columns it throws this stackoverflow error.